# cmake for compiling nfs-ganesha in fedora-20

Tags: build, fedora

when I am trying to start `cmake` on terminal of fedora-20 by typing command

ccmake ../nfs-ganesha-master/src

then a window opened in terminal of `ccmake` which is available on following link -(under topic-running cmake on unix)
             http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/runningcmake.html

when I am pressing c to configure then a error is being displayed as-

ERROR:

```
CMake Error at cmake/maintainer_mode.cmake:48 (message):
   Maintainer-DDEBUG_SYMS=ON is not a valid build type.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   CMakeLists.txt:77 (include)


 CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:364 (message):
   Cannot find GLUSTER GFAPI runtime.  Disabling GLUSTER fsal build

 CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:382 (message):
   Cannot find CEPH runtime.  Disabling CEPH fsal build

 CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:400 (message):
   Cannot find LUSTRE runtime.  Disabling LUSTRE fsal build

 CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:437 (message):
   Cannot find XFS runtime.  Disabling XFS build

 CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:455 (message):
   Cannot find ZFS runtime.  Disabling ZFS build

CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:467 (message):
   jemalloc not found, falling back to libc

 CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:503 (message):
   libnfsidmap not found, disabling USE_NFSIDMAP

 CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:523 (message):
   Samba 4 wbclient not found.  Disabling MSPAC_SUPPORT

 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:640 (message):
   No CMakeLists.txt found in libntirpc
```

Errors occurred during the last pass

```
CMake Version 2.8.10.2
Press [e] to exit help
```

Answer (score 1):

For the error message "No CMakeLists.txt found in libntirpc", the message is disappeared in my case after I downloaded `ntirpc` from https://github.com/nfs-ganesha/ntirpc and put them into folder `nfs-ganesha/src/libntirpc/`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Just use "--recurse-submodules" when cloning nfs-ganesha.

git clone --branch ${GANESHA_VERSION} --recurse-submodules https://github.com/nfs-ganesha/nfs-ganesha